# how to find a file that was created programmatically directly from my iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've created an image file in an application and stored it in the fileDirectory using the following code:

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
UIImage* videoImage = [self resizeImage:[UIImage imageWithData:self.videoImageData] toWidth:width andHeight:height];
NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(videoImage, imageQuality);
[imageData2 writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.png"] atomically:YES];
```

now from my iPhone device how can i find and open this file?

Comment: Why doesn't your app provide this facility if it's something you want the user to be able to do?

Comment: @trojanfoe this code is for testing purposes i wanted to see the image i'm transferring to the server on my device it's not something the user should do.

Comment: Add the facility to your app but only make it available in "developer mode" (using a compile-time constant, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode you can go to **Window**->**Organizer** and select the **Devices** tab.

Under the device in the panel on the left you will see **Applications**. Select your application to see the file system for the app sandbox. Select **Download** to save all the data to the mac (as a package file).

You can right-click a package file to browse as a folder by selecting **Show Package Contents** from the context menu.

Comment: great! the delete button is all or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to connect your iPhone to a Mac to see it. [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageData2 writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myfile.png"] atomically:YES];
```

you missed back slash

Comment: Nope; you don't need the **forward** slash.